# Invalid Authentication Headers When Using Anonymous Authentication

Tags: c#, forms, forms-authentication

I am trying to implement forms authentication in my application, but I am getting the "Invalid Authentication Headers" error when browsing the locally IIS hosted application. Below is the screenshot of what I see in browser window.

[image]

Here is code snippet from web.config added for Forms Auth

```
   <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />     
        <authentication mode="Forms">
          <forms loginUrl="login.aspx" protection="None" />
        </authentication>
        <authorization>
          <deny users="?" />
        </authorization>
      </system.web>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `<authorization>` tag, you have used `<deny users="?" />`. This is going to deny access to the anonymous user.

Comment: Even changing it to <allow users="*"></allow> doesn't seem to be working. Same error